# Align rotated Texts in SwiftUI HStack

Tags: ios, alignment, swiftui, text-alignment

I am trying to trailing align rotated texts (top aligned after rotation?). I have tried different combinations of the `HStack alignment parameter`, each Text's `alignmentGuide() ViewModifier` and a `custom VerticalAlignmentGuide` but was not able to achieve the desired result.
I did refrain from using the `.frame() ViewModifier` since the text's scale factor might change depending on the amount of Text Views.

Needed alignment shown with red line:

[image: image with alignment description]

Base code:

```
HStack {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(height: 80)
        Text("Text 1")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            .padding(.top, 30)
    }
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(height: 80)
        Text("Text 2")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            .padding(.top, 30)
    }
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(height: 80)
        Text("Text 34")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            .padding(.top, 30)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]try this:

```
VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("Text 1")

            Text("Text 2")

            Text("Text 34")

        }.rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
```

Comment: Apologies mate, I just realized I oversimplified my example. I am going to update my question. Gave you an upvote. My bad...

Answer (score 2):

ok, my last one now, hope you are satisfied ;)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                Text("Text 1")
                    .frame(width:100, height:100, alignment: .trailing)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            }
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                Text("Text 2")
                    .frame(width:100, height:100, alignment: .trailing)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            }
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                Text("Text 345")
                    .frame(width:100, height:100, alignment: .trailing)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

new answer for your comment update:

```
HStack {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                Text("Text 1")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90), anchor: .bottomTrailing)
                    .padding(.top, 30)
            }
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                Text("Text 2")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90), anchor: .bottomTrailing)
                    .padding(.top, 30)
            }
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                Text("Text 34")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90), anchor: .bottomTrailing)
                    .padding(.top, 30)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It must be center aligned with the Rectangles (see updated picture above). The goal is to create a X-Axis description for several Bar Charts. There will be a dynamic number of bar charts so the width of the bar chart rectangles might change to fit more bars.